# Android Widget: previewImage size

Tags: android, widget

I have a widget in Android for which I am setting a previewImage. Unfortunately, I am having issues figuring the good size for the widget: if it's too big, it gets cropped at the bottom of the frame.

I have been trying to find the recommended size, or even better, the pixel dimensions of this frame where the preview image gets displayed, but I cannot find it in the documentation.

Does anyone please know where to look for that information please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The emulator has an application for creating a preview with just the right size:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview

My suggestion would be to grab a previewImage of your widget with that application and then look at the size.

Comment: This is possible, but isn't there a recommended size provided by Android, if I want to do my own preview image inside Photoshop in the first place please?

Comment: @user1777907: Might be worth running the Widget Preview once to see what it outputs and use that as a guideline. I can tell you that the Google Music app has a 631 × 201 px preview image that sits in the `no-dpi` folder, if that's of any help.

Comment: "emulator has an application" , are we talking about an app in android emulator? or is it a computer application with the sdk? confused i am.

Comment: For those wondering: The application they're talking about is in the Android emulators and it's called _Widget Preview_. You can find the app in the launcher between the other apps.

Comment: On my emulator this app "Widget preview" fails - saying it cannot save the preview. However, for 1x1 preview a size around 110x110 works for me.

Answer (score 9):

According my tests widget preview is connected to widget XML file.

**widget preview for widget 1x1:**

picture size: width=138pixels, height=138pixels

xml file definition: android:minHeight="50dp", android:minWidth="50dp"

**widget preview for widget 2x1:**

picture size: width=236pixels, height=138pixels

xml file definition: android:minHeight="50dp", android:minWidth="120dp"

Answer (score 7):

I would suggest that the size of your preview should directly reflect the "default" size of your widget.

As per the Android website: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/widget_design.html

It gives a guide on the size of multiple widget "cell": `70dp × n − 30dp` (where n is the cell count)

So, for instance, 2x1 cell widget would be: `110x40`, `165x60` and `220x80` in MDPI, HDPI and XHDPI respectively.

From experience though, and I've not managed to 100% confirm this yet, on XXHDPI devices (Nexus 10 etc) this rule stops being relevant as the cell size is larger.

Answer (score 1):

As there is next to nothing on this topic on the web, and not definite answer here, these are some my observations:

- Application definitely draws images from mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi folders, so it might make sense to have different resolutions for those folders
- I think that it makes no sense to attach pixel resolution to cell size - there is the same space for all widgets
- Based on previous, and on observation that Google use 201 vertical size for its widget preview as stated here, it makes sense to use that for vertical resolution and multiply that with cell ratio for horizontal resolution. There is probably some horizontal value above which you should do the opposite (calculate vertical resolution from horizontal), but for now it is best to guess it...
- It is not always a good idea to use directly image from Widget preview from emulator (though this function produces error on my emulator). It is usually better if preview takes most of the image, so there shouldn't be paddings on image. I think Google uses this to make its digital clock preview as big.

Answer (score 0):

Gmail app has a single png in drawable-nodpi-v4, size 638x504.