# Widget preview image

Tags: android, android-widget

My app preview image looks like this:
[image]

How can I make it look like the WhatsApp Chat preview, small with shadow. Also other apps in my phone use the same type of preview.

My widget xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/appwidget"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minWidth="320dp"
    android:previewImage="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="300000" >
</appwidget-provider>
```

Manifest:

```
<receiver
            android:name=".activities.MyWidgetProvider"
            android:label="Example Widget">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually I have noticed this all shortcuts and not widgets, they all have this look.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have set your launcher icon as widget preview image.

```
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  ...
  android:previewImage="@drawable/widget_preview">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I suggest you to make a screenshot of your widget with the emulator, which has an application (*Widget Preview*) for creating a preview with just the right size.

Then, you can also edit the picture if you are not satisfied.

Anyway, be sure to put it on *drawable-nodpi*.

Official guide to follow: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#preview
For other dev experience, see this link: [Android Widget: previewImage size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13574860/2013835)

Comment: I cant find this application, is it supposed to be in the app drawer?

Comment: @daka when you launch the emulator, it is in the app list. At the bottom, you will find _Widget Preview_ (cause by default it will range them by name). I found it on an emulated Nexus 5X Android Oreo 8.0.

Comment: I don't see it, I'm using Oreo too

Comment: Maybe something is wrong with the emulator. Try to re-create it. If this is not working, I suggest you to ask a separate question, where you can also put some screenshot.

Comment: The Widget Preview app will only show up on an emulator running Android 8.0 or older.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have placed ic_launcher as widget previewImage

- You have to make a custom image, which have large image as Alpha in background, and on it place your icon in small size on top-right corner.

I have done same thing by generating custom image for previewImage with help of photoshop and its working.

Thank you.

Comment: I understand. But many apps have the same preview (large image as Alpha in background, and on it icon in small size). It cant be that all apps did exactly the same design. This is some default OS design and not photoshoped.